# Coining Binary variables into one in R

Tags: r

Hope all goes well.

I am working on a data set that has 7 binary variables ( they are all 0 and 1) and they are not mutually exclusive.

I need to convert them all into one categorical variable which will have 2^7 levels.
I was wondering if anyone has done such a thing in R before?

I really appreciate your time and answer.

Best,

Comment: Can you give an example with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1), x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), x3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
               x4 = c(1, 0, 1, 0), x5 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), x6 = c(1, 1, 0, 0), x7 = c(1, 0, 0, 1))
data <- unite(data, combine_x, 1:7, remove=FALSE)
data$combine_x <- factor(data$combine_x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Semal. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste` something like this should work.

```
#create dataframe 
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(rbinom(100,1,.5), rbinom(100,1,.5),rbinom(100,1,.5)))
#paste columns together using apply to loop over rows   
df$new<-apply(df,1,function(x) paste(x, collapse =""))
```

Any non NA character can be used in the collapse argument (for example collapse = ":" if you want to seperate records by :). Output:

```
> head(df)
  V1 V2 V3 new
1  0  1  1 011
2  0  0  1 001
3  1  1  1 111
4  0  0  1 001
5  0  1  0 010
6  1  0  0 100
```

Comment: Thanks so much Niek. I really appreciate that.

Comment: If you like mine or sermal's answer could you accept one of them? This way your question doesn't remain "unanswered"